# Decoding problems with Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression

I have to implement the LZW algorithm but I have found some trouble with the decoding part.
I think the code is right because it works with a example I've found somewhere on the web: if I initialize my dictionary as follows

```
m_dictionary.push_back("a");
m_dictionary.push_back("b");
m_dictionary.push_back("d");
m_dictionary.push_back("n");
m_dictionary.push_back("_");
```

and my input file has the string `banana_bandana`, I get the following results:

`compressed.txt`: 1036045328

`decompressed.txt`:banana_bandana

But if I initialize the dictionary with all the 255 ASCII characters, the decoding process fails miserably. I think the problem rests in the number of bits used on the codes because when I'm going to decode, I always read from the input file char by char (8 bits) instead the correct number of bits, I guess.

Below is the code of my implementation of this algorithm:

```
template <class T>
size_t toUnsigned(T t) {
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << t;
  size_t x;
  stream >> x;
  return x;
}

bool LempelZivWelch::isInDictionary(const std::string& entry) {
  return (std::find(m_dictionary.begin(), m_dictionary.end(), entry) != m_dictionary.end());
}

void LempelZivWelch::initializeDictionary() {
  m_dictionary.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    m_dictionary.push_back(std::string(1, char(i)));
}

void LempelZivWelch::addEntry(std::string entry) {
  m_dictionary.push_back(entry);
}

size_t LempelZivWelch::encode(char *data, size_t dataSize) {    
  initializeDictionary();

  std::string s;
  char c;

  std::ofstream file;
  file.open("compressed.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i) {
    c = data[i];

    if(isInDictionary(s + c))
      s = s + c;
    else {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < m_dictionary.size(); ++j)
        if (m_dictionary[j] == s) {
          file << j;
          break;
        }

      addEntry(s + c);
      s = c;
    }
  }

  for (size_t j = 0; j < m_dictionary.size(); ++j)
    if (m_dictionary[j] == s) {
      file << j;
      break;
    }

  file.close();

  return dataSize;
}

size_t LempelZivWelch::decode(char *data, size_t dataSize) {    
  initializeDictionary();

  std::string entry;
  char c;
  size_t previousCode, currentCode;

  std::ofstream file;
  file.open("decompressed.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  previousCode = toUnsigned(data[0]);

  file << m_dictionary[previousCode];

  for (size_t i = 1; i < dataSize; ++i) {
    currentCode = toUnsigned(data[i]);

    entry = m_dictionary[currentCode];
    file << entry;
    c = entry[0];
    addEntry(m_dictionary[previousCode] + c);
    previousCode = currentCode;
  }

  file.close();

  return dataSize;
}
```

And this is the function that reads the input files:

```
void Compression::readFile(std::string filename) {
  std::ifstream file;
  file.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

  if (!file.is_open())
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  m_dataSize = file.tellg();
  m_data = new char [m_dataSize];

  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  file.read(m_data, m_dataSize);
  file.close();
}
```

My guess is the decoding problem resides in reading the input file as a array of `chars` and/or writing to the compressed file the `char`s as `size_t`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the actual question here?  It sounds like you have a theory for why it doesn't work; have you tried debugging to see whether it's true?

Comment: When you read in data to decode, you *certainly* need to read the same sized chunks as you wrote out, so if (for example) your encoding with 9-bit codes, you need to read 9-bit codes as you decode as well.

Comment: @Jerry, that's what I was thinking about but how should I do it? Read the compressed file bit by bit instead byte by byte or manipulate the data after the file being loaded to the memory?

Comment: I would read chunks into a buffer, and keep a point to the next *bit* to read from the buffer. To read from the buffer, read to the end of the next byte, shift appropriately, `or` in the remainder of the 9-bit chunk, and advance the pointer to the bit following that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are outputting the dictionary indices as ASCII encoded numbers. How are you going to tell the sequence 1,2,3 from 12,3 or 1,23.
You need to encode the data in an unambiguous way using either 9-bit (10, 11 or whatever) numbers or some sort of prefix-free code like huffman coding.

Comment: And what would be the best way to manipulate the data in that way? Is there any library to perform bitwise operations on files?

Comment: Well if you choose 9-bit numbers you could create a base-72 encoding (lcm(9, 8) == 72; so use groups of 8 9-bit tokens and output them as 9 8-bit characters) in the same way base-64 encoding works